# Disabling certain rows based on condition in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I need to disable certain rows based on a particular condition. This is my code:

```
<ReactTable    
  data={this.state.categoryTable}
  loading={this.state.loading}
  noDataText="Please select a country template"
  columns={[
    {
      Header: 'Category/Lot',
      accessor: 'category_name'
    }, {
      Header: "Display Name",
      accessor: "display_name",
      Cell: this.renderEditable
    }, {
      Header: 'Price(per month)',
      accessor: 'price',
      Cell: this.renderEditable
    }, {
      Header: 'Spots',
      accessor: 'spots',
      Cell: this.renderEditable
    }>
```

I need to disable Price and Spots row when the Category/Lot is equal to "South America"

Comment: What do you mean by disable a row?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing `]` for your `columns` array, and a closing `}` afterwards, ending your `columns` prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that in order to access another field in current row you should access `row.row`,

So, your code should be written something like that:

```
<ReactTable    
  data={this.state.categoryTable}
  loading={this.state.loading}
  noDataText="Please select a country template"
  columns={[
    {
      Header: 'Category/Lot',
      accessor: 'category_name'
    }, {
      Header: "Display Name",
      accessor: "display_name"
    }, {
      Header: 'Price(per month)',
      accessor: 'price',
      Cell: row => row.row.category_name=="South America" ? ***disable*** : row.value
    }, {
      Header: 'Spots',
      accessor: 'spots',
      Cell: row => row.row.category_name=="South America" ? ***disable*** : row.value
    }]}
 />
```

Now, I am not sure exactly lwhat do you mean by disabling a row.. but you can handle a state with collections of "disabled" indices in table or some solution like that.

Or, if you are rendering some other component inside a cell, then you could just pass a "disable" to some property:

```
Cell: row => (<SomeSubComponent disable={row.row.category_name=="South America"} value={row.value} />)
```

Hope I helped :)